# Converting a global exit signal to an exception

Tags: python, multithreading, exception, pynput

I'm working on an terminal interface audio player based on VLC and Curses.

I was recently advised on a [SE Code Review post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/235983/terminal-interface-audio-player-based-on-vlc-curses/236017#236017) to utilize exceptions to exit the program rather than using a `global` boolean as a signal.

However, when I converted the code to use the `SystemExit` exception, it stopped exiting fully and instead hangs until the terminal window is closed. I believe the issue is related to Pynput's listener and how I'm handling the thread it creates, but I'm unsure.

**Using a boolean:**

```
import sys, os
from pynput import keyboard
from functools import partial

import cfg
from view import View
from player import Player

exit_signal: bool = False
def on_press(key: keyboard.KeyCode, view: View, player: Player):
    """Handle input"""
    global exit_signal
    key = str(key).strip('\'')
    if str(key) == 'p':
        view.notify('Playing...')
        player.play()
    elif key == 'a':
        view.notify('Paused')
        player.pause()
    elif key == 'n':
        view.notify('Skipping Forward...')
        player.skip_forward()
    elif key == 'l':
        view.notify('Skipping Back...')
        player.skip_back()
    elif key == 'q':
        view.notify('Exiting...')
        exit_signal = True
        del player
        del view
        return
    view.update_ui(player.get_metadata())

def tick(view: View, player:Player):
    """For functions run periodically"""
    metadata = player.get_metadata()
    view.update_ui(metadata)

view = View()
player = Player()

view.notify("Ready!")
with keyboard.Listener(on_press=partial(on_press, view=view, player=player)) as listener:
    while exit_signal == False:
        tick(view, player)
    listener.join() # merge to one thread
    os.system('reset') # clean up the console
```

**Using SystemExit:**

```
from os import system
from pynput import keyboard
from functools import partial

import cfg
from view import View
from player import Player


def on_press(key: keyboard.KeyCode, view: View, player: Player):
    """Handle user input"""
    key = str(key).strip('\'')
    if str(key) == 'p':
        view.notify('Playing...')
        player.play()
    elif key == 'a':
        view.notify('Paused')
        player.pause()
    elif key == 'n':
        view.notify('Skipping Forward...')
        player.skip_forward()
    elif key == 'l':
        view.notify('Skipping Back...')
        player.skip_back()
    elif key == 'q':
        view.notify('Exiting...')
        del player
        del view
        raise SystemExit
    view.update_ui(player.get_metadata())


def tick(view: View, player: Player):
    """For functions run periodically"""
    metadata = player.get_metadata()
    view.update_ui(metadata)


view = View()
player = Player()

view.notify("Ready!")
listener = keyboard.Listener(
    on_press=partial(on_press, view=view, player=player))
listener.start()
try:
    while True:
        tick(view, player)
except SystemExit:
    listener.join()     # merge back to one thread
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
```

I would expect both snippets to behave the same and exit when 'q' is pressed, but instead only the boolean method functions correctly.

This code is also on [github](https://github.com/ReticulatedSpline/openDAP). Thank you for your time.

Comment: According to the docs [here](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html#monitoring-the-mouse), it states: "Call `pynput.mouse.Listener.stop` from anywhere, `raise StopException` or return `False` from a callback to stop the listener."

Comment: It could be that perhaps your program quits at `listener.start()` on `raise StopException`, but then it gets stuck inside the `while True: tick(view, player)` line -- and the function `tick` never raises `SystemExit`, so your program will never reach the `except` statement, or its end.

Comment: @FelipeFaria Thanks, your observations led me to another solution which I've posted below.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer to the original question I posted as it doesn't use exceptions, so I won't mark it as a solution. Anyways, as pointed out in the comments, returning false on a Pynput callback ends the listener thread. Monitoring the status of that listener thread can tell you when to close the second "UI" thread:

```
def on_press(key: Key, view: View, player: Player):
    """Handle input"""
    # boring code
    elif key == 'q':
        view.notify('Exiting...')
        return False # kills listener thread
    return True

def main():
    view = View()
    player = Player()
    listener = Listener(on_press=partial(on_press, view=view, player=player))
    listener.start()
    while listener.running: # once the listener thread exits, end the program
        tick(view, player)
    del player
    del view
```